# Ubuntu install error acpi

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation

I have usb flash drive ubuntu 16.04 lts, made with rufus
Booting from it, selecting install or try Ubuntu without install
I get the following error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please provide your hardware info.

To install any Linux distro, you have to:

1. Download *.ISO image of distro you desire to install.
2. Verify the MD5 checksum value of kernel with the value which can usually be found either on website where you downloaded *.ISO from or somewhere included in *.ISO image (mount the ISO and browse it to find this info).
3. Download UNETBootin and burn that *.ISO on USB. Or use CD/DVD burning software  WITH ABILITY TO VERIFY that disc was recorded PROPERLY (On Windows, Padus Disc Juggler is one of those or on Linux k3b).
4. In BIOS turn off "Virus Protection" if you have it - some BIOSes won't allow writing in area of HDD where Setup needs to write.

Edit: Just thought of this: make sure your BIOS is in ACPI mode, NOT APIC.